# POST request body parameters description in AZURE API Managment

Tags: azure-api-management

I tried to import API by using Swagger, But unfortunately not getting the body parameters description of POST requests. I tried to add an operation manually, But in that request body description allows only text. But I want to display my API should describe the each and every parameter with an example like in the below URL

[Azure sample API with parameters description in the request body description](https://docunate.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/56caf397f02497067852f6e4/operations/56caf4d1f02497067852f6e5)

How can I do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding the details of your request body you can enter raw HTML into the description box, e.g.:

[image]

It looks like that is how the site you linked manages to get custom tables in that section.

Comment: Thanks @darth_phoenixx. Is it only way to the display body parameters description?

Comment: As far as I am aware that is the only way to achieve it, yes.